# How to have variable callbacks in PassportJS?

Tags: oauth, passport.js

PassportJS's [OAuth gets configured this way globally](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/oauth/):

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , OAuthStrategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuthStrategy;

passport.use('provider', new OAuthStrategy({
    //... 
    callbackURL: 'https://www.example.com/auth/provider/callback'
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    //...
  }
));
```

and similar for the other strategies, like Twitter, Facebook, etc.

If my app is serving multiple different dynamic domains, how do I handle the callbackURL? Is it possible to skip the callback URL and only send it on each request, where I'll know which URL is being served?